# Regex to match any combination of words but not a single decimal

Tags: c#, regex

I have a **long** regex containing `(?:\S+ ){0,4}`

That should match: (it's already doing this correctly)

```
2 Terry White 
Tramal 100 
Asmol 2.5 
2.5%
```

or anything matching that, **except** a single decimal or price.

It should not match: (I don't know how to do this exception)

```
870
6.75
$17.60
```

Is that even possible?

Thanks everyone for your input. Just FYI for those who are curious, here is one of the shortest "long regex" it is used in (you can find it near the end)

```
^ {0,5}(\d{4}[A-Z]) +((?:\S+ )+(?: {0,10}K\+)?) *(\.\.|\d+) +(?:[A-Z#\*] *)?(\.\.|\d+(?:\.\d{1,4})?) +(?:[ab] *)?((?:\S+ ){0,4}) *([A-Z]{2}) {0,10}$
```

Comment: Do you have flexibility to write your code in the opposite way?  In other words write your regex to match a single decimal or price (pretty trivial).  If it matches, then reject the input; otherwise accept it.

Comment: No, as I said it is only a part of a long regex. Thanks anyway

Comment: Was worth a shot.  Sometimes you can work around a tough problem by thinking about it in a different way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do is going to work with regex alone (based upon the updated information). The problem comes in (and this applies to my answer below) that your use of `(?:\S+ ){0,4}` will capture the `Asmol 2.5`, and then my suggestion of lookbehind will find the `2.5` and cry "foul." I think you're trying to accomplish too much with regex alone. You may be able to include some more lookarounds to accomplish this, but it's going to get pretty gnarly, and your current regex is pretty hairy as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "a single decimal" since your first failing example appears to be an integer, but you might try:

```
^(?!\$?\d+(?:\.\d+)?$).+$
```

Based upon your comments, I'm thinking a negative lookbehind might be more of what you are looking for:

```
(?<!\$?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

Comment: +1 for [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Also, you can use the asker's original expression in place of the `.+` near the end, as the case may be.

Comment: @Wiseguy Perhaps, but the "or anything" anything comment leads me to believe a `.+` would be more applicable.

Comment: Thanks Kennetch, but it is only a part of a long regex, I can't use ^ or $ to match beginning or end of line

Comment: @aximili Well without knowing the "long regex", it's only conjecture at this point.

Comment: @aximili Is there some kind of marker you can use to help bound the lookbehind? Can you capture a piece of the "long regex" just before where you would be inserting this? Then a backreference could be used to bound.

Comment: I edited the question :) However it is only one of them, I need to be able to reuse this regex in others as well. I only know a little about negative lookahead, do you think you can use it?

Comment: Accepting this as the answer. It may be impossible to achieve what I want, but using negative lookahead/lookbehind seems to be the closest solution.